# Spring Path Variable that accepts email with special character

Tags: spring-boot

I have spring boot rest application (spring boot 2.1.8.RELEASE).

It has an API that accepts an email address and it works well on most emails like:

```
sampleemail@mailtest.com
sample-email@mailtest.com
sample.email@mailtest.com
sample_email@mailtest.com
```

but it does not work with `sample+email@mailtest.com`

Below is my API method:

```
@PostMapping("/public/sendEmail/{email:.+}")
public void sendEmail(@ApiParam(value = "Account email", required = true) @PathVariable String email) {
    doSomethingToThis(email);
}
```

Same issue if I use `/public/sendEmail/{email}` instead of `/public/sendEmail/{email:.+}`.

What should I change so that it will accept email with `+` character like `sample+email@mailtest.com`?

TIA

Comment: I use 2.2.5 and '+' works as a path variable so it might be a bug/improvement that has been done. Did you try using "/public/sendEmail/{email}" as the request path?

Comment: yeah I also tried that one and I got the same result

Comment: If only there is a way to fix/handle this case without upgrading the version

Comment: Since upgrading spring boot is not possible, I just used request body (json payload) instead of passing the email as path variable. This is the easiest and fastest change I can do for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add one **'/'** in the end of the `@Postmapping`, so it will consider it as a whole string.

From:

```
@PostMapping("/public/sendEmail/{email:.+}")
```

To:

```
@PostMapping("/public/sendEmail/{email}/")
```

The complete one is like below

```
@PostMapping("/public/sendEmail/{email}/")
public void sendEmail(@ApiParam(value = "Account email", required = true) @PathVariable String email) {
    doSomethingToThis(email);
}
```

Comment: Just tried this but it does not work on `2.1.8.RELEASE`. Also, this needs an additional `/` on my api calls or I get 404 error

Comment: In that case, did you try to see is the value coming properly at least to the interceptors/filters ?